# Why can't the dragons see into the future in Fairy Tail's episode 196 and 197?

Tags: fairy-tail

In Fairy Tail, episode [196](https://fairytail.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_196) to [203](https://fairytail.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_197), [Ultear](https://fairytail.fandom.com/wiki/Ultear_Milkovich) uses the spell [Last Ages](https://fairytail.fandom.com/wiki/Last_Ages).

> Her spell had caused everyone in the world to clairvoyantly envision one minute into the future, preventing [many deaths and tragedies]. *(Quote from Ultear's Wikipedia page, lined above)*

What is the cause for the dragons not being able to see into the future?